# Replacing HTML Document error

Tags: community, document, folder

We have a html document which we're using in SF Community and I'm trying to replace it. But I get the following error:

> Error: The branding document folder where the logo image is stored is
>   Private. You must change it to Public.

I just don't get what's that mean, the doc itself is in public folder, images referenced by the html is also in a public folder. I'm not sure where to look next. Searching for this error didn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are already using the HTML in the branding header of your community. So it is locked out. Remove it first from the community and the do the replacement and add it back to the com.. At least that worked for me.

Comment: To be more precise: in Setup go to All Communities -> click Manage on your community, then Administration -> Branding -> leave Header of Footer empty then Save. Thanks Leo

Answer (score 3):

One additional suggestion if the answer does not work for you (as was my case)

1. If the file you used under Community Management | Administration | Branding wasn't originally in the Document folder `Communities Shared Document Folder` then..
2. Add the file to `Communities Shared Document Folder` and remove it from any other folder (so you don't have duplicates to worry about in the future)
3. Then you can replace and alter as needed over time